# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How are anime seasons released?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/how-are-anime-seasons-released)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why does Brad Pitt cameo in these manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/why-does-brad-pitt-cameo-in-these-manga)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Where did Scar's other tattoo come from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/where-did-scars-other-tattoo-come-from)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Do the symbols on Kazuki's shirt mean anything?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/do-the-symbols-on-kazukis-shirt-mean-anything)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How did all of the weird creatures end up in class 2A?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/how-did-all-of-the-weird-creatures-end-up-in-class-2a)

  **Net Score: -12** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 12)
- [What is the first transforming/morphing mobile suit/robot in anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/what-is-the-first-transforming-morping-mobile-suit-robot-in-anime)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there a special meaning to the class name "2-H" (2-ふ)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/is-there-a-special-meaning-to-the-class-name-2-h-2)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Isn't Flora's ability inefficient?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/isnt-floras-ability-inefficient)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What exactly is the technique Madara uses to control Obito?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4285/what-exactly-is-the-technique-madara-uses-to-control-obito)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why do the giants in Shingeki no Kyojin start to look like the characters that got eaten?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/why-do-the-giants-in-shingeki-no-kyojin-start-to-look-like-the-characters-that-g)

  **Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 7)